# If I'm holding two weapons, can I momentarily hold one under my arm to free a hand?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, actions, free-action, move-action

Let's say I have Two-weapon Fighting, and I am wielding a light weapon in each hand. I have an ability that lets me conjure a certain item as a swift action. Can I momentarily hold one of my light weapons under an arm so I can conjure the item and hand it to an adjacent teammate?

What kind of action would it be to temporarily stow a light weapon like this? Would it be faster than just sheathing the weapon?

Comment: Thanks everyone. After hearing what you all are saying, and thinking about it some more, it makes sense to me that putting a weapon under one's arm momentarily would not be a free action, but would be a move action to manipulate an object (which would provoke an AoO). The player might as well just sheath the weapon (also a move action provoking an AoO).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know it's hard to prove a negative, but I'm pretty confident that there are no rules for this.

The only thing that is left is to adapt the rules we already have (which you're familiar with).

Unsheating and Sheathing (I'm going to capitalize them, so that it is clear that they are mechanical terms in this context) also apply to weapons that don't have a sheath, such as a maul or an axe.

They represent the act of moving your weapon from some position where you have it on your person but you're not wielding it to your hand, and viceversa.

This is in contrast with stowing and retrieving items (weapons included) from a backpack or similar bags.

As such, even putting your weapon under your arm should be considered Sheathing, and retrieving it should be Unsheating it.

Comment: Tucking something under an arm is much easier than sheathing; not sure I see much support either from the rules or from real life for these to be same.

Comment: If so what prevents characters from just putting weapons or other items under their arms instead of sheating whenever they need a free hand? Under the level of detail that the rules allow, notwhitstanding rulings, you either have a weapon in your hand, sheated, dropped or stowed.

Comment: The word is “sheathed,” with an h, by the way. I know English is not your primary language, no judgement, but just so you know. Anyway, I can see your argument and it is plausible, but I don’t see enough evidence to convince me that it is _necessarily_ the case.

Comment: @KRyan I'm with Z on this one. Were this an option, the game'd *make* it an  option. In the middle of combat while folks are trying to kill you, it seems to me as risky and as complicated to sheathe a weapon as it is to *hold a weapon in your armpit!* That said, I wish it were *easier* to sheathe a weapon, and I do think the game could offer more granularity than carry in hand, sheathe, drop, or stow, even though to the typical adventurer it hasn't.